# How to split an array into multiple columns in Presto

Tags: sql, arrays, split, row, presto

I have data that looks like this

| order | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{item_id=11, item_price = 1000}, {item_id=22, item_price = 3000}] |
| 2 | [{item_id=11, item_price = 1000} |
| 3 | [{item_id=22, item_price = 3000}, {item_id=33, item_price = 3500}] |
| 4 | [{item_id=22, item_price = 3000}, {item_id=33, item_price = 3500}, {item_id=11, item_price = 1000, qty=1}] |

I would like to achieve something like this

| order | item1 | item2 | item3 | price1 | price2 | price3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 22 |  | 1000 | 3000 |  |
| 2 | 11 |  |  | 1000 |  |  |
| 3 | 22 | 33 |  | 3000 | 3500 |  |
| 4 | 22 | 33 | 11 | 3000 | 3500 | 1000 |

I dont know how to write my query to split the items & price into different columns, and the number of items for each order does not have a limit (it can be greater than 3).

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why do you need all items as separate columns? Common usecase is to have them as separate rows.

Comment: hello @GuruStron there are many other fields in this data, i dont want to split these items as rows as many info will be repeated over and over.